# How should the libqmi be linked?

Tags: c++, c, libqmi

I've tried to use libqmi but I can't get through the linker. It keeps saying "undefined reference" on libqmi functions. Any suggestions what is needed?

Paths and libraries are available for gcc, the symbols are inside libqmi-glib, looks like everything is in place.

The code is the simplest possible, I think.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GFile *qmi = g_file_new_for_path("/dev/cdc-wdm0");
    printf("%li\r\n", (long int)(qmi));
    g_object_unref(qmi);
    return 0;
}
```

And the build goes like this:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/libqmi-glib/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0/ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ whatever.c -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lqmi-glib -lglib-2.0
```

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: `C` and `C++` are two different languages.  Please pick one

Comment: Exact error message is:
    /tmp/ccdei99o.o: In function `main':
    whatever.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `g_file_new_for_path'
    whatever.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

And yes, C and C++ are different languages. This code can be compiled by both of them and as a final target it'd be C++.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the link to `libgobject-2` and `libgio-2`.

Anyway, the best way to compile a program using libqmi is to use pkg-config as that knows all the cflags and ldflags you should be using; e.g. you could probably do this, assuming you installed libqmi in /usr/local:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig gcc $(pkg-config --cflags qmi-glib) whatever.c $(pkg-config --libs qmi-glib)
```